# Create date in karaf shell

Tags: java, shell, date, karaf

I'm trying to create a date object from a long (timestamp) in a karaf shell (karaf version=2.4)

It should be as simple as `new java.util.Date 0` but it returns

> Error executing command: Error when instantiating object of class
>   java.util.Date

The stack trace is

> java.lang.Exception: Error when instantiating object of class
>   java.util.Date caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at
>   java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:615)[:1.7.0_55]

So it appears that it thinks that 0 is a string. Creating a variable doesn't seem to help :

```
> a = 0
> $a getClass
returns java.lang.Long
> new java.util.Date $a
returns the same error as above.
```

Any help ?

Comment: Try wrapping in quotes maybe? I'm just guessing here, don't know the karaf shell. - Since you can use some Java stuff, maybe casting it will help?

Answer (score 1):

On Karaf 3.0.3 - it works out of the box.   So, I *suspect* a bug in earlier versions.

```
karaf@root()> new java.util.Date 0
Time                 0
Year                 70
Month                0
Date                 1
Hours                1
Minutes              0
Seconds              0
Day                  4
TimezoneOffset       -60

karaf@root()> new java.util.Date
Time                 1430085930875
Year                 115
Month                3
Date                 26
Hours                23
Minutes              5
Seconds              30
Day                  0
TimezoneOffset       -60
```

Comment: Yes I also agree it's a bug, but any idea of a workaround ?